# How to add an special item on the begining of the ListView

Tags: android

I have some tabs on the top of the screen.Below that theres a ListView.

My problem is that,I want to set an item "Go To Up Folder" on the very beginning of the ListView and that should be look alike a ListView items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ListView.addHeaderView()` method.